# Add additional tab within access

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I'm not sure if this is possible but here goes. What I wish to do is create an additional tab within my report as I wish to add an extra text box after details.

When adding the textbox within the details tab it repeats after every grade as shown below.

[image]

If the textbox is placed in the footer it only shows at the bottom of the page shown below.

[image]

I wish the textbox to appear as shown in the image below.

[image]

Ideally I would like to add an additional tab below details within the design view to place this textbox and a page break. Shown below is the design view.

[image]

If anyone can give some light on how this can be done that would be great.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I'd say you simply need to switch on the footer for the `Students_StudentID` section. You do this in Grouping and Sorting.

Comment: That's the ticket, sorry I am new to access thank you though.

Comment: np, I wasn't sure if I was missing something. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch on the **Footer** for the Students_StudentID section.

This is done in the **Group, Sort and Total** pane.